# Deleted files in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

So the case is that I moved the files of my project into a different folder and then I opened the project folder with the android studio again. At first all the files were there. Then I tried to build it and everything got disappear and only the .iml files are left inside the project. Is there any way to recover the files?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating the files with the same names and in the toolbar go:

VCS -> Local History -> Show History.